# Is the phrase על נסיך שבכל יום עמנו at the end of Modim implying that we rely on miracles?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei

I understand that there is a halacha that we are not allowed to rely on miracles. (Don't recall source of that rule.) At the end of the "Modim" prayer we thank G-d for על נסיך שבל יום עמנו - "For the miracles that are with us daily."

What "miracles" are we referring to? It seems that if we are thanking G-d 3 times daily for miracles, then in a sense, aren't we relying on G-d to make these miracles happen every day?

Comment: (Pessachim 64b) "Lo samchinin anisah"

Comment: Just because they exist mean we rely on them?

Comment: I don't know if there is any source but my gut tells me that there is a difference between relying on a miracle regarding something which could be in our power vs. relying on the miraculous nature of god's creation which we cannot control. If we believe that the whole world is toleh al blimah, suspended on nothingness, we are relying on the miracle of god's keeping the earth going. We can't do anything about that and without that "miracle" we would cease to be. But this is all just my 1st impression.

Comment: Nahmanides on Leviticus 26:11 discusses the concept of all natural events surrounding Israel actually being hidden miracles. That is what I have in mind when I say those words.

Answer (score 3):

Rabbeinu Yehuda Ben Yakar mentions that נסיך here may refer to נסיונות, that we are thanking Hashem for the challenges that He gives us every day.

Etz Yosef says that these miracles are not referring to miracles that are constantly happening.  It is referring to the open miracles which are always with us *in our minds*, meaning we always are aware of these open miracles that have happened.

> שהם עמנו בידיעתנו

So בכל יום עמנו does not mean that they are happening every day, but that we know of them, or think of them, every day.

However, Iyun Tefillah states that this is referring to miracles which Hashem does every day.  He seems to understand it to refer to hidden miracles, which are referred to in the verse עושה נפלאות לבדו.  This does not mean we do extraordinary things with the expectation of the miracle, it means that part of our normal daily function is that hidden miracles happen.

Siach Yitzchak explains that these miracles are with the Jewish people, meaning that they are not necessarily happening to every individual every day, but they are with the Jewish people as a whole.  According to this, the miracles being referred to are not necessarily happening to any individual on any given day.